# Continuity is essential in the following question?

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$, and assume that $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Prove that there is a real number $s<1$ such that  $$f(x)\leq sg(x) \ \hbox{ for all } \ x \in [a,b].$$

This is a question from Michael C. Reed- Fundamental ideas of analysis.What I thought  about the question is the following: since $f$ and $g$ are defined on a closed bounded interval, if we  assume that $f$ and $g$ are not continuous, these functions have to possess some jump discontinuities and so by assumption that $f(x)<g(x)$, I thought we would always have that there is some $s<1$ (in some cases, any $s$ will work) such that $f(x)\leq sg(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. To what I think, the real number $s$ in the question should be in the open interval $(0,1)$ and in this case we have to use the continuity assumption and I proved the question in the case that $s$ has to be in the open interval $(0,1)$. Continuity is essential in this case, I thought. If there are some examples that says that continuity is essential for finding $s<1$, please can you give me some examples?I couldnt construct such an example.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your formulae are missing?

Comment: This question is incomplete. "Assume that $f(x)$..."?

Comment: @Furor: this is duplicate of the question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034983/continuity-is-necessary-in-the-following-question there also it seems you are having some trouble.

Comment: I dont understand, there should be a problem about website. I wrote the question twice but it seems no good. there is the rest of the question and it doesnt appear as I wrote it

Comment: Edited your question--looks like the problem is fixed. That was odd; the site definitely was chopping off your question

Comment: To clarify: the issue with the original version of this post is that it used less-than `<` in ordinary text with no whitespace to the right, in such a way that they were interpreted as HTML tags. Now that the `<` symbols are all inside dollar signs, it's working again. I rolled back an edit that partially undid the fix

Comment: That's helpful, thanks @Ben.

Comment: in the case f(x) < g(x) < 0, no need to use the continuity assumption

Answer (score 1):

the problem indeed needs continuity of the functions to work. Suppose you have two funktions h and g such that $h(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b)$ and $h(b)=g(b)$. Since $h$ is continous, obviously you can't find a suitable $s$ such that $h(x)<sg(x)$ on $[a,b)$. Now define $f$ as $f(x)=h(x)$ if $x\in[a,b)$ and $f(b)<g(b)$. Then it follows that you cannot find a suitable such that $f(x)<sg(x)$ on $[a,b)$

Comment: Ok, but f(x) < g(x) for all x in [a, b].

Comment: yes $f,g$ suffice the condition $f(x)<g(x)$ since on $[a,b)$ $f(x)=h(x)<g(x)$ and $f(b)<g(b)$

Answer (score 0):

Try $g(x)=1$, $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ on the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: What I am saying is when the function f is defined on closed bounded interval, it has to have jump discontinuities and maybe there is no need to use the continuity to prove that there is some s < 1 such that f(x) <  s g (x)

Comment: Just a minute, I see now. Thanks really.

Comment: In the case f(x) < g(x) < 0, no need to use the continuity assumption?

Comment: Yeah in the negative valued case, continuity is not necessary.